# Connecting Django User model with custom models error using one_to_one_field

Tags: python, django, database, model

This is the models.py file of my Django project. I am getting this error in 5 line of the code below. I wanted to connect Django default User model to my model by OneToOneField to provide multiple account functionality to my project, but I am stuck at this error that I don't understand.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class DailyTrack(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'Profile', default='')
    income = models.IntegerField()
    expense = models.IntegerField()
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Income {self.amount} Income {self.amount}'
```

Error is in the 4th line at the default field, I tried removing default or adding it but I am unable to understand this.
There is an error for

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, dailytrackapp, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying dailytrackapp.0003_dailytrack_user...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'null'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\Desktop\MultiProj\DailyTrack\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\Desktop\MultiProj\DailyTrack\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 971, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2388, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\NIitin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'null'.

NIitin@Nitin MINGW64 ~/Desktop/MultiProj/DailyTrack
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'dailytrackapp':
  dailytrackapp\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model DailyTrack

NIitin@Nitin MINGW64 ~/Desktop/MultiProj/DailyTrack
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, content types, dailytrackapp, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Why have you specified a `default` on the `OneToOneField`?? (Literally does not make sense). Furthermore the default is an empty string `''`! The users tables pk is a **number** hence a default would be numeric (even if present). Anyway the default doesn't make sense just remove that. You will also have to delete the migration `dailytrackapp.0003_dailytrack_user` and any others that depend on it (or edit it and remove the default yourself).

Comment: Thank you for your help. but the problem is solved I shouldn't have used OneToOneField but manytoonefield(foreignkey). oneToOneField also worked by deleting the db file once and rerunning makemigrations and migrate command.
I was confused that which relationship should I use. Now my app is working perfectly fine.